# Why doesn't SSIS OLE DB Command transformation insert all the records into a table?

Tags: sql, ssis, insert, oledb

I have an SSIS package that takes data from Tables in an SQL database and insert (or update existing rows) in a table that is another database.

Here is my problem, after the `lookup`, I either insert or update the rows but over half of the rows that goes into the insert are not added to the table.

For the insert, I am using an Ole Db Command object in which I use an insert command that I have tested. I found out why the package was running without error notification but still not inserting all the rows in the Table.

I have checked in sqlProfiler and it says the command was **RCP:Completed** which I assume means it supposedly worked.

If I do the insert manually in sql management studio with the data the **sql profiler** gives me (the values it uses toe execute the insert statement with), it works. I have checked the data and everything seems fine (no illegal data in the rows that are not inserted).

I am totally lost as to how to fix this, anyone has an idea?

Comment: Your question is very vague: the title mentions "date format" but the question does not; you said you "found out" why the package doesn't do you what you want, but you didn't explain what that means; you don't give an example of an INSERT statement that works manually; you don't mention any specific data types or how you know that there is no illegal data; you don't mention the SSIS version etc.

Comment: Ole Command is used when there are complex SQL statements involved.
Can we see the SQL statement inside the SQL command?

Comment: @Pondlife, tried to fix it and found out it wasn't the date but something else, forgot to change the title, changed the title

Comment: @Internet Engineer the statement wasn't complicated, it was a simple insert. That was the way I had been showed to do it, I have been doing that wrong for a while I think, thanks for clearing it up

Comment: so, even with the oleDb Destination, the problem is the same. The thing strange here is that I put all the data in a buffer table before the lookup without problem.

Comment: @Siva
you understood correctly. I created a dummy table and all the rows got inserted correctly. I then changed the name of the dummy table to the name of the original table and it failed. I tried deleting the original and dummy table, then creating a new table with the original table name and it still fail. If I change the name of the newly created table to something else, it works though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any specific reason to use OLE DB Command instead of OLE DB Destination to insert the records?

**EDIT 1:**

So, you are seeing x rows (say 100) sent from Lookup transformation match output to the OLE DB destination but only y rows (say 60) are being inserted. Is that correct? Instead of inserting into your actual destination table, try to insert into a dummy table to see if all the rows are being redirected correctly. You can create a dummy table by clicking on the New... button on the OLE DB destination. It will create a table for you matching the input columns. That might help to narrow down the issue.

**EDIT 2:**

What is the name of the table that you are trying to use? I don't think that it matters. I am just curious if the name is any reserved keyword. One other thing that I can think of is whether there are any other processes that might trigger some action on your destination table (either from within the package or outside of the package)? I suspect that some other process might be deleting the rows from the table.

Comment: Broadcasting_IBI was the name of the table, voting up, there was a process that was deleting some rows, can't believe I did not think about it, thanks